# Vertically center unordered list in page header Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website for a local business with the help of Bootstrap, and they would like their contact details on the right hand side of the page header (not the navbar). I am trying to use an unordered list and Bootstrap's column grid system to show their phone number and email address, and potentially other content such as a Facebook like button. I need some help to vertically center the content, because currently the phone number is at the bottom of the page header and the email address is being covered by the navbar.
My code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Excellent Carpet Cleaning - Sample 1</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
<!--header image-->
<div class="page-header">
        <center><a href="index.html"><img src=http://goo.gl/Yk0lCv width=50%/></a></center>
    <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right">
        <ul>
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>555-5555</li>
            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>someone@example.com</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!--top navbar-->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Current Offers</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://facebook.com/aidansexcellentcarpetcleaning">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is linked to bootstrap.min.css which can be downloaded [here](http://getbootstrap.com) and my own external stylesheet which is:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    border-color: #0000a0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #0000a0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #0000a0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #0000a0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #0000a0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #0000a0;
    }
}
/*end navbar*/
body {
    padding-top: 0;
}
.page-header {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.page-footer {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #0000ff;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #bb0000;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS or make a http://www.jsfiddle.net. I'm struggling to see a problem without it, although I'm not particularly experienced with bootstrap.

Comment: Sorry to leave out such an important part

Comment: hmm, any reason for <span></span>X instead of <span>X</span>?

Comment: <span></span> is just Bootstrap's requirement to show the glyphicons and the part after it is to show the contact number and email address as text on the page, not as part of the span. Changing it did nothing but change the font-family of the phone number

Comment: please put it in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Let me know if my answer was helpful or if I could change it to become more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**For Extra Small Devices:**

```
<div class="page-header" style="text-align:center;">
    <center>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="http://goo.gl/Yk0lCv" width="50%"/></a>   
    </center>
    <div class=" hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone "></span> 555-5555 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> someone@example.com</div>
</div>
```

I took the contact information and stuck it underneath the image, so when the device is sized to an extra small screen it will not inconvenience the mobile user to see it laying inside of the drop down menu (not a pretty site).

**For All Other Sizes:**

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Services</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Current Offers</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="https://facebook.com/aidansexcellentcarpetcleaning">Facebook</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact Us</a>

            </li>
            <li class="hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 555-5555
                <br/> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> someone@example.com</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I added your contact information and put it inside of the navigation bar, to be in one single list tag, this way both items will size appropriately and also become hidden as the user is sizing to an extra small device.

**[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29L6p/3/)**